# How to insert an uncommon special character into a html attribute?

Tags: html, unicode, icons, html-entities, html-encode

**My approach / what I've found so far:**

I want to insert an icon as the value attribute for an input tag as follows:

```
<input class="icon-" value="&#977154;" />
<!--the class is used to assign the icon font-->
```

I noticed that the CSS implementation of icon fonts has special characters as the content to be included as the icon:

```
.icon-search:before {
    content: "\e902";
}
```

So [I looked for](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ee902/index.htm) the equivalent HTML Entity code in order to include it as the value attribute and found that the corresponding code is `&#977154;` and also that it isn't a valid Unicode character.

So, I wonder how to encode the document so that it renders that character as the corresponding icon (after all, it's being rendered properly when implemented through the class, so perhaps there's a way).

**Disclaimer:**

I know there are other more "natural" ways to do something similar, but I want to know the scope of this possibility.

Comment: Well you're right, 977154 (or U+0EE902) is not a valid character (it is “not assigned”). What do you expect to happen?

Comment: `&#977154;` is codepoint U+EE902, which is not assigned in Unicode.  `\e902` is codepoint U+E902 (`&#59650;`), which is a private-use codepoint. The two are completely different codepoints.

Comment: @roeland I expected it to display my custom icon because it is defined within the custom icon font

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right, it worked! Thanks a lot :) -I got confused because when I searched it, U+EE902 was better ranked in the results.

Comment: @RemyLebeau BTW, please write the "official" answer, so I can vote it as the proper solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#977154;` is codepoint `U+EE902`, which is not assigned in Unicode.

`\e902` is codepoint `U+E902` (`&#59650;`), which is a private-use codepoint.

The two are completely different codepoints.